# Putting TSV files into Data Frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe, csv, dplyr

I am attempting to put multiple TSV files into a data frame in R.

Even when providing absolute paths, the list.files function results in 0 characters, and the dataframe has 0 columns and rows. I have already loaded the dplyr and data.table libraries.

Any help would be much appreciated.

```
file_list <- list.files(path = "/Users/salahmekhalalati/Downloads/Volumes/Listvolumes/sub-011_space-cropT1w_desc-subfields_atlas-bigbrain_volumes.tsv", 
                        pattern = "*volumes*.tsv", 
                        full.names = TRUE, 
                        recursive = TRUE)
volumes_dt <- data.frame(NULL)
for(file in file_list){
  temp_dt <- fread(file, na.strings = c("NA", "NaN", "", "?"))
  volumes_dt <- bind_rows(volumes_dt, temp_dt)
}
list.files(file_list)
# character(0)
volumes_dt
# data frame with 0 columns and 0 rows
```

Comment: The `pattern=` argument of `list.files` takes a regular expression, not a grob. You seem to be using the wrong syntax. Try something like `pattern = ".*volumes.*\\.tsv$"`

Comment: There's also the `glob2rx` function that allows you to continue using glob-style expressions: `pattern = glob2rx("*volumes*.tsv")`

Comment: It's generally a bad idea to iteratively `rbind` or `bind_rows` frames; instead create a list of frames and only after the `for` loop combine that. For example, `out <- list(); for (file in file_list) { ...; out <- c(out, list(temp_df)); }; volumes_dt <- bind_rows(out);`.